# CSS: 100% height not working on div with display: table

Tags: css

I have a problem which causes headache for me for hours now. I have the following html:

```
<ion-view class="menu-content" view-title="Postkarte">
    <ion-content>
        <div class="postcard-container">
            <div class="postcard">

            </div>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

And the following css:

```
.postcard-container {
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.postcard {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-position: center center;
    background-image: url("../img/frames/postcard_00.png");
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

The result is this:

[image]

So the 100% width is working but the 100% height is ignored. Why?

Comment: Please provide full code that will allow us to reproduce the issue. This is likely due to the height (or lack of) of the element(s) containing it.

Comment: You will need to set the height of all parent elements to 100%. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8464208/3751577

Comment: The problem is i dont know the css of the parent elements since they are from the ionic framework.

Comment: There is no way to control the `height` of a `table`. This includes elements that have `display: table;`. The height always adheres to the content.

Comment: @Mulgard, if you provide a full reproducible example we may be able to suggest some possible ways to tackle the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is **no way** to control the `height` of a `table`. This includes elements that have `display: table;`. The `height` always adheres to the content in a `table`.

You will have to find some other method to achieve your vertical centering.